# How to adjust the size of a RecyclerView to show the first 3 elements and then scroll to see the rest of the elements?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in one layout and in another layout the layout of the element that is added to it.

What I want to do is that in the `RecyclerView` only the first three elements are seen and then to see the next ones you have to scroll.

That is, if there is one item, the size of the `RecyclerView` is equal to the size of one item. If it contains two, let the size fit those two items. The same with three but from the three elements, you need to scroll. I have tried using `LinearLayoutManager` but I see all the added elements.

Comment: your question title and what you're trying to achieve sound quite a bit different. to only show 3 items is simple, to adjust them based on the amount of items, i'm not sure is so simple

Comment: Yes, you are right, I edited the title so it is not so confusing. If you can help me in this question I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It would be better if you draw it out.

Comment: if i could help you, i would have :) that's why i said what you're trying to achieve sounds a bit more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are better ways to do this, but I found one trick on SO that helped me with this - wrap your recycler view with **ConstraintLayout** and the set on **RecyclerView** - "**layout_constraintHeight_max**":

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/Id_const_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Id_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Id_const_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Id_const_layout"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/YOUR_ITEM" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It worked on my project with height of 200, adjust it accordingly to your item height*3.